# SQL 2008: SPROC throw error so I can catch in ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

I've got this simple SPROC:

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT UserName FROM Party WHERE UserName = @UserName)
    BEGIN
        --This means it exists, return it to ASP and tell us
        SELECT 'This record already exists!'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --This means the record isn't in there already, let's go ahead and add it
        SELECT 'Record Added'

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        INSERT INTO Party
            (EmailAddress, UserName, LoginPin)
        VALUES (@EmailAddress, @UserName, @LoginPin)
    END

END
```

How do I throw an exception from the SPROC so that my .NET C# app can catch the error using a TRY CATCH block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `RAISERROR` in your stored procedure.

See this [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321903) on the topic.

Also, see the [MSDN reference on RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx)

Comment: I don't mean a TRY CATCH within the SPROC... unless that's the only way to throw an error?

Comment: @dcolumbus: If you check the first link (Microsoft article) it provides an example using a stored proc that uses RAISERROR and has the try..catch in VB.NET, which you should be able to easily emulate in your C# app.

Comment: Thanks nybbler... I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any issues. It really works quite well once you see it in action.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be throwing an error at all. I've declared the error message, added the RAISERROR and commented out the SELECT. Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code? It's worth mentioning that RAISERROR will **require a severity of 11 to 19 to cause control to jump to the catch block**. Also, the state setting for RAISERROR must be between 1 and 127 only.

Comment: @dcolumbus: can you update your original question with the new sproc that has the RAISERROR in it??